# Solenoidal fields in $D$ spatial dimensions

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, gauge-theory, vector-fields

In the T. Sakurai paper cited below, page 209,  the author  discusses how the magnetic field can be written in terms to the cross-product
$$ \vec B = \vec\nabla \chi \times \vec\nabla \eta,$$
for two scalar potentials $\chi$ and $\eta$.

**My question:** is this generalizable to higher dimensions and higher forms? In particular, in $D$ dimensions, can I always represent a closed $p$-form $d\omega$ by
$$ d\omega = d\chi_1 \wedge\cdots\wedge d\chi_p ,$$
or is there somehow something special about the magnetic field case?

Further if this is not generically true, what are necessary/ sufficient conditions for it to hold?

Edit: I originally came across this claim about magnetic fields here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3977. In this paper, the author cites the work: Sakurai T., "A New Approach to the Force-Free Field and Its Application to the Magnetic Field of Solar Active Regions," Pub. Ast. Soc. Japan, Vol. 31, 209, 1979.

Comment: Could you add some more context, for those who do not have a copy of Sakurai on hand?

Comment: .. and *which* Sakurai? Title and edition please.

Comment: Can you work out the [Clebsch representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch_representation) for solenoidal fields in 4d?

Comment: about the second question on exact p-form, refer to de-Rham cohomology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology

Comment: Construction of Monge/Clebsch potentials *need not* refer to fluid dynamics papers. *Nothing* is special to the magnetic field. The decomposition holds for all solenoidal fields. I suspect your conjecture is correct, but I don't know how to construct the (scalar) potentials for D=4, the way construction is standard for D=3. Perhaps the MSE is friendlier to this type of question.

Comment: Your closed p form conjectured is the  "velocity" of a Nambu bracket evolution in D=p phase space. p=2 is  Hamiltonian mechanics.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial answer. Let $B$ be a closed $p$-form magnetic field strength in $D$ spatial dimensions with $p\geq 1$.
OP is then essentially asking if $B$ is can be written locally$^1$ as
$$ B~=~\mathrm{d}\chi_1\wedge\ldots \wedge\mathrm{d}\chi_p ~?\tag{1} $$

From [Poincare Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) we know that there exists a locally defined $(p\!-\!1)$-form magnetic gauge potential $A$, so that $B=\mathrm{d}A$.

Eq. (1) is clearly possible with $\chi_1=A$ if $p=1$, so let's assume $p\geq 2$ from now on. Then $A\to A +\mathrm{d}\lambda$ has a $(p\!-\!2)$-form gauge symmetry $\lambda$.

Let us try to count DOF. The $p$-form $B$ has at least
$$\begin{pmatrix} D \cr p\!-\!1 \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} D \cr p\!-\!2 \end{pmatrix}~=~\begin{pmatrix} D\!-\!1 \cr p\!-\!1 \end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$
DOF, which should not be bigger than the $p$ DOF on the rhs. of eq. (1). This is generically only possible if

1. $B$ is dual to a vector field, i.e. $p=D-1.$

   - The case $p=2$ follows from [Darboux' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem)/the [Clebsch representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch_representation), cf. an above comment by Cosmas Zachos.
   - In the case $p\geq 3$, the gaugesymmetry $\lambda\to \lambda +\mathrm{d}\xi$ has a $(p\!-\!3)$-form gauge-for-gauge symmetry $\xi$, so a more precise counting shows that $B$ actually has more than $p$ DOF, i.e. eq. (1) is generically not possible.
2. $B$ is a top-form with 1 DOF, i.e. $p=D$.

   - The case $p=2$ follows from Darboux' theorem.

--

$^1$ The corresponding global problem can carry additional topological obstructions.